# Filter Json with Ids contained in csv sheet using python

Tags: python, json

I have a csv file with some "id". I imported a json file and I needed to filter from this Json only the ids that are in the worksheet
Does anyone knows how to do that? I have no idea, I am very new in python. I am usin Jupyter notebook

How to filter data fetching from variable var_filter

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

# read csv with ids
var_filter = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
display(act_filter)


# Load json
with open('file.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)
print(data)
```

The json structure is:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "179328741654819",
        "t_values": [
            {
                "t_id": "963852456741",
                "value": "499.66",
                "date_timestamp": "2020-09-22T15:18:17",
                "type": "in"
            },
            {
                "t_id": "852951753456",
                "value": "1386.78",
                "date_timestamp": "2020-10-31T14:46:44",
                "type": "in"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "823971648264792",
        "t_values": [
            {
                "t_id": "753958561456",
                "value": "672.06",
                "date_timestamp": "2020-03-16T22:41:16",
                "type": "in"
            },
            {
                "t_id": "321147951753",
                "value": "773.88",
                "date_timestamp": "2020-05-08T18:29:31",
                "type": "out"
            },
            {
                "t_id": "258951753852",
                "value": "733.13",
                "date_timestamp": null,
                "type": "in"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: whats a sample id's file looking like? also, you are wanting to use `pandas` for this?

Comment: @rv.kvetch The csv file contains only one column called "id". The lib pandas is because I also need to create a table after I read that json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the elements in the data variable and check if its `id` value is in the dataframe's `id` column. Simple method below, see [this article](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-check-column-contains-a-value-in-dataframe/) for other methods

Note that I convert the value of the JSONs `id` to an int as that is what pandas is using as value type for the column

**code**

```py
import json
from pprint import pprint
import pandas as pd


var_filter = pd.read_csv("id.csv")

# Load json
with open("data.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)


result = []
for elem in data:
    if int(elem["id"]) in var_filter["id"].values:
        result.append(elem)
pprint(result)
```

**id.csv**

```
id
823971648264792
```

**output**

```
[{'id': '823971648264792',
  't_values': [{'date_timestamp': '2020-03-16T22:41:16',
                't_id': '753958561456',
                'type': 'in',
                'value': '672.06'},
               {'date_timestamp': '2020-05-08T18:29:31',
                't_id': '321147951753',
                'type': 'out',
                'value': '773.88'},
               {'date_timestamp': None,
                't_id': '258951753852',
                'type': 'in',
                'value': '733.13'}]}]
```

Comment: Thank you @Edo Akse its help a lot